# Android Google maps APIv2 InfoWindow and Markers

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-imageview, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using Google maps APIv2 for android. I've implemented MapFragment, put markers where I need, added custom InfoWindow for markers.

The issue is - I have **AsyncImages** in my **InfoWindow** and have **ProgressBar** there. The thing is - **ProgressBar** doesn't spin, and Image doesn't set after I got it from cache. AsyncImages does work well. I've tested it into another class.

I've replace my **AsyncImages** view with just single **ProgressBar** - the same. It doesn't spin. 

Any suggestions?

### UPD.

Spinner doen't spin cause of

> Note: The info window that is drawn is not a live view. The view is
>   rendered as an image (using View.draw(Canvas)) at the time it is
>   returned. This means that any subsequent changes to the view will not
>   be reflected by the info window on the map. To update the info window
>   later (e.g., after an image has loaded), call showInfoWindow().
>   Furthermore, the info window will not respect any of the interactivity
>   typical for a normal view such as touch or gesture events. However you
>   can listen to a generic click event on the whole info window as
>   described in the section below.

So the question is - how to realize AsyncImages from web/cache on Maps in the best way?

Create Views array somewhere apart of ***getContentInfo()*** method and also create listener smth like *OnImageDownloaded*?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?  I am having a similar problem.

Comment: Not yet. I've left it. Luckily, I don't need AsyncImages on Map Markers right now. But I still have no idea how to realize it.

Comment: i am having the similar issue, downloading images and showing them in a marker window. i couldn't find a solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated at [Google Maps Android API v2 Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#info_windows):

> Note: The info window that is drawn is not a live view. The view is
>   rendered as an image (using `View.draw(Canvas)`) at the time it is
>   returned. This means that any subsequent changes to the view will not
>   be reflected by the info window on the map. To update the info window
>   later (e.g., after an image has loaded), call `showInfoWindow()`.
>   Furthermore, the info window will not respect any of the interactivity
>   typical for a normal view such as touch or gesture events. However you
>   can listen to a generic click event on the whole info window as
>   described in the section below.

Perhaps you should try to call `showInfoWindow()` somewhere again in your code.

Comment: Thanks, i totally missed this small note. But the problem is still here. I guess than I should create Views to show in InfoWindow not in _getContentInfo()_ method but somewhere else ,and create another listener to  notify me than image is downloaded and set into view. Looks quite annoying

Comment: quite annoying indeed... but seems plausible, please post it if you manage to make it work! I'm working on something similar and this could be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here.

I think that calling showInfoWindows() for a spinning ( indeterminate ) progress bar doesn't make sense to me, and I'm also not sure it works. ( of course showinfoWindows may have sense for a horizontal progress bar) 
So I went for one of the following three solutions,

1) left the progress bar not animated beside a "Loading..." text, it gives an idea to the user at least.
2) put the loading spinning wheel somewhere else in the UI.
3) Using a dialog fragment to show loading procedure but it really depends on the feel you want to achieve with your app.

Personally I've chosen the first one.

I really hope that Google will fix this in future.